# How to add user in phpmyadmin ? there is nothing about adding user under user account

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using XAMPP v3.2.3 PHP/7.1.28. I cannot find add user link:

[image: screenshot phpmyadmin]

Comment: There is a big message with "You do not have privileges to manipulate with the users!" as content. With which user are you logged in?

Comment: Hi @thmspl  here is what I have changed in  my config.inc  /* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;  and when I login I just type localhost/phpmyadmin &  it redirects me to the home page

Comment: Try to enable the configuration `DisableIS` by adding `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['DisableIS'] = true;` to your config file. And try it again after a restart.